Convert Unicode const(uint)* to a dlang character type
I'm writing an SFML app in D using bindbc.sfml. System clipboard functions for Unicode in this SFML bindings get and return Unicode clipboard text as const(uint)* where uint is a Unicode code.
How could I convert it to and from dlang character types such as wchar[] or wstring?
I've figured out that for SFML text input events giving single uint codes in event.text.unicode I can do the following:
wstring ws = cast(wstring)[event.text.unicode];

but what to do with such pointers like const(uint)*? Is it even a pointer to an array of uints or am I mistaken?
After several try and error approaches the best I get is
// copied text: Hello
const(uint)* ct = cfClipboard_getUnicodeString();
writeln(to!wstring(*ct)); // prints 72

which gives only the first character in the clipboard text, but as a unicode code (e.g., 97 for latin a)
and this
// copied text: Hello
const(uint)* ct = cfClipboard_getUnicodeString();
writeln(cast(wstring)[*ct]); // prints H

which also gives only the first character, but as an printable char.

I'm not sure where the prototype for cfClipboard_getUnicodeString is, but if it is returning a uint*, it's probably a pointer to dchar code points.
With caution, I'd say the answer is that the uint* is a zero-terminated array of utf32 code points. What I'd try is:
import std.string;
auto dstr = fromStringz(cast(const(dchar)*)ct);

If that doesn't work, let me know where that function is defined, and we can go from there.

Your code also gives just the first character. I'm starting to think that it's something wrong with CSFML on Linux. The prototype of sfClipboard_getUnicodeString is in window.d file of bindbc.sfml and it looks like this: const(sfUint32)* sfClipboard_getUnicodeString();. The sfUint32 is just an alias for D's uint type.

By the way here's the Clipboard section on CSFML site: https://csfml.1l.is/api/Window/Clipboard.html It says it returns a Unicode string as UTF-32.

Got it working! If I cast the clipboard data const(uint)* to const(dchar)* then fromStringz correctly gives the full string rather than just 1 character. auto dstr = fromStringz(cast(const(dchar)*)ct);

Oh sorry! I wrote wchar, and meant to write dchar.
